# How to upload artifacts from Maven into Nexus repository?

Tags: gradle, repository, nexus

I am using Sonatype Nexus version 3.1.0-04.

I have a build that is failing due to some missing artifacts in my Nexus repository.
     http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.0.0/protoc-3.0.0-windows-x86_64.exe

When I search the repository, I do not see this .exe file, all I see is the POM file.

When I look on the Maven repository, I see the files I need.
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.0.0/

Does anyone know of a way to force a sync of my Nexus repository with the Maven repository?

Comment: Some things to look at: 1) Are you proxying that repo? 2) Do you see the in "browse storage" 3) What is the exact error when the build fails? 4) What exact GAV coordinates are specified in the build?

Comment: 1. The repository type is proxy.  2. I do not see the .exe file in the repository.  3. Build error below.  4. Where would these coordinates be specified?

Comment: * What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':pcrfcore:protobufToolsLocator_protoc'.
> Could not find protoc-linux-x86_64.exe (com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-3).
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://1xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.0.0-beta-3/protoc-3.0.0-beta-3-linux-x86_64.exe

Answer (score 3):

The problem I encountered was a result of having the "Strict Content Type Validation" option selected.  When I unchecked this option, the build ran and pulled down the artifacts w/o error and populated the data in Nexus.

https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/50